# Aframe audio issue

Tags: aframe

I have included below audio asset in my scene. In two ways tried it....

```
<audio id="hover" src="resources/assets_data/hover.mp3"></audio>
```

and

```
<a-asset-item id="hover" src="resources/assets_data/hover.mp3" response-type="arraybuffer"></a-asset-item>
```

When I am trying to play this sound in four menu elements I am getting below error... and hover sound is playing only on first menu curved image....

> components:sound:warn Sound not loaded yet. It will be played once it
>   finished loading

**Code:**

```
<a-curvedimage  src="#a" transparent="true" 
                height="0.5" radius="0.9" theta-length="40" rotation="0 240 0" position="0 1.74 -1.4" sound="on: mouseenter; src: #hover" selectable>
        </a-curvedimage>

        <a-curvedimage src="#b" transparent="true" 
                height="0.5" radius="0.9" theta-length="40" rotation="0 190 0" position="0 1.74 -1.4" sound="on: mouseenter; src: #hover" selectable>
        </a-curvedimage>

        <a-curvedimage src="#c" transparent="true" 
                height="0.5" radius="0.9" theta-length="40" rotation="0  130 0" position="0 1.74 -1.4" sound="on: mouseenter; src: #hover" selectable>
        </a-curvedimage>

        <a-curvedimage src="#d" transparent="true" 
                height="0.5" radius="0.9" theta-length="40" rotation="0  80 0" position="0 1.74 -1.4" sound="on: mouseenter; src: #hover" selectable>
        </a-curvedimage>
```

Comment: Maybe a similar issue to [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353368/play-sound-component-with-animation-using-a-frame) Worth checking out at least.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working when i used an audio tag with the `preload: auto` attribute:

```
<a-assets>
   <audio id="mysound" crossorigin="anonymous" src="...">
</a-assets>
```

Try it out [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/successful-thrill?path=index.html:25:0).